# Change VkFormat at runtime

Tags: format, vulkan

At the moment I am working on some performance measurements in Vulkan. I want to measure the difference between uncompressed formats such as `VK_FORMAT_R32_SFLOAT` and compressed formats such as `VK_FORMAT_BC6H_UFLOAT_BLOCK`. Is there a built-in feature in Vulkan that allows switching between formats at runtime?

Since the data is created at runtime, it is unfortunately not an option to compress the data offline. I also know that I could implement the compression myself, but BC6 is so complex that I would like to avoid it if possible.

If Vulkan does not support this feature, is there some C++ lib that I could use instead?

Comment: "*Since the data is created at runtime, it is unfortunately not an option to compress the data offline.*" If you want to measure the performance difference between formats, then it doesn't matter where the data comes from. So there's no reason you couldn't load some BC6H data from a file, even if it's not particularly meaningful for the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Vulkan does not have built-in on-the-fly image compression. According to a quick Google search, the [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Compress) library seems like it should do what you want.